# Feature extraction and Matching with Cuda/Opencv/Python

Tags: python, opencv

I share a working code of feature extraction and matching using ORB, my problem is that I need to make it work with more than two images could someone help me ? ()

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
import cv2
import numpy as np

GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15
max_features = 9000
orb = cv2.cuda_ORB.create(max_features)
matcherGPU = cv2.cuda.DescriptorMatcher_createBFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
# Read the images as normal
npMat1 = cv2.imread("C:\Users\Geddy\Desktop\0.png")
npMat2 = cv2.imread("C:\Users\Geddy\Desktop\1.png")#cv2.imread("path_to_reference_image")

# Load the images onto the GPU
cuMat1 = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat2 = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
cuMat1.upload(npMat1)
cuMat2.upload(npMat2)

# Convert the color on the GPU
cuMat1 = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(cuMat1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cuMat2 = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(cuMat2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
# Create the CUDA ORB detector and detect keypoints/descriptors
kps1, descs1 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(cuMat1, None) # Both are returned as GPU Mats
kps2, descs2 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(cuMat2, None)
matches = matcherGPU.match(descs1, descs2)
matches2=sorted(matches,key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)
numGoodMatches = int(len(matches2) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
matches2 = matches2[:numGoodMatches]  
kps1c = orb.convert(kps1)
kps2c = orb.convert(kps2)
imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(npMat1, kps1c, npMat2, kps2c, matches2, None)
cv2.imwrite("gpu_matches.jpg", imMatches)
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but if you want to match more than two images you'll need to use a for loop:

```
<code>for image in images:
    kps, descs = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(image, None)
    matches = matcherGPU.match(descs1, descs2)
    matches2=sorted(matches,key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches2) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches2 = matches2[:numGoodMatches]  
    kps1c = orb.convert(kps1)
    kps2c = orb.convert(kps2)
    imMatches = cv2.drawMatches(npMat1, kps1c, npMat2, kps2c, matches2, None)
    cv2.imwrite("gpu_matches.jpg", imMatches)
</code>
```

Comment: Yes I want to do it with several images, for that I need to extract the characteristics of the first image and perform the matching with the second, then the second image with the third, then the third with the fourth and so on. thanks for your help but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

```
from distutils.command.upload import upload
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob as gb

GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT = 0.15
max_features = 9000
orb = cv2.cuda_ORB.create(max_features)
matcherGPU = cv2.cuda.DescriptorMatcher_createBFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
   
img_files = ['0.png', '1.png', '2.png', '3.png']
image_gpu= cv2.cuda_GpuMat()

for i in range(len(img_files)):
    screenshot = cv2.imread(f"C:\Users\charlie\Desktop\{img_files[i]}")
    image_gpu.upload(screenshot)
    screenshot = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(image_gpu, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(image_gpu[i-1], None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(image_gpu[i], None)
    kp1 = orb.convert(kp1)
    kp2 = orb.convert(kp2)
    matches = matcherGPU.match(des1, des2)
    matches2=sorted(matches,key=lambda x: x.distance, reverse=False)
    numGoodMatches = int(len(matches2) * GOOD_MATCH_PERCENT)
    matches2 = matches2[:numGoodMatches]
```

I think this is a good way but I have this error:

**kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndComputeAsync(image_gpu[i], None)
TypeError: 'cv2.cuda_GpuMat' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).